# Bootstrap css glyphicons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm trying for the first time to use the bootstrap glyph icons and it's not working the way I wanted.

I want a left and right icons so I choose `glyphicon-chevron-left` and `glyphicon-chevron-right`.

This is my html :

```
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#home_carousel">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
```

This is the css :

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-animation: PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

This is how it looks now :

[image]

This is how I'd like it to look :

[image]

For some reason `padding` property makes the left arrow go outside of the box.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

[image]

Actually the span is the box, and the ::before is the arrow.

**Edit 2:**
Should I do this some other way? Place a glyph icon inside a box?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the 10px padding on the icon?

Comment: You're referencing the icon and it's background with the same style, its applying a padding within a padding. Try removing the `.glyphicon-chevron-left` from the style definition

Comment: @Rook please see my edit, removing it from style just removes the box yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the padding rule you have and instead set the width, height, and line-height you get what you want:

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  line-height:48px;
  width:48px;
  height:48px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-animation: PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         PrevBtn 1.5s infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

[**bootply example**](http://www.bootply.com/0bUgEhlvUC)